# vim substitute function don't work with or operator

Tags: vim, substitution

Using `:echo substitute("abc","a\|d","e","")` command, I want to get the answer like `ebc`. But the answer is still `abc`. When I use `:s/a\|d/e/` replace the text, I can get `ebc`. I want to know why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String literals have their own backslash escapes (see `:help expr-quote`) so you need to double the backslash so one of them gets through to the regexp parser.

Comment: Best to Use single quotes for regex patterns. E.g. `substitute('abc', 'a\|d', 'e', '')`. Also using a character class would be better than alternation. E.g. `[ad]`

Answer (score 1):

Quotes problem is always a nightmare.

In order to reduce it you can use 'single quoted' strings \cite(@peterRinker et al) and very magical
(`\v`) modifier (no need to escapa + | () and some more operator).

Example:

```
:echo substitute("Name Surname",'\v(\w)\w+ (\w+)','\2, \1',"")
```

-- Surname, N